# std::vector behavior, move and copy

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I was doing a neural net in cpp during free time in order to get some more experience in C++11. However I ran into some problems that a I cannot figure out myself.

```
struct neuronsLayer
{
    vector<real> ac;

    neuronsLayer(int s)
    {
        std::cout<<"neuronLayer 1"<<std::endl;
        ac = vector<real>(s,0.1f);
    }
    neuronsLayer(const neuronsLayer& nl)
    {
        std::cout<<"neuronLayer 2"<<std::endl;
        ac = vector<real>(nl.ac);
    }
    neuronsLayer(neuronsLayer&& nl)
    {
        std::cout<<"neuronLayer 3"<<std::endl;
        ac = std::move(nl.ac);
    }
    neuronsLayer operator=(const neuronsLayer& nl)
    {
        std::cout<<"neuronLayer 4"<<std::endl;
        return neuronsLayer(nl);
    }
    neuronsLayer(){ std::cout<<"neuronLayer 5"<<std::endl;}
    ~neuronsLayer(){}
};
```

This is a layer implementation, then :

```
struct network
{
    vector<neuronsLayer> hiddens;
    vector<neuronsConnection> synaps;
    real alpha;

   //std::initializer_list

    network(vector<int> layers)
    {
        alpha = 1.f;
        hiddens = vector<neuronsLayer>();//+2
        for(int& l : layers)
        {
            hiddens.push_back(neuronsLayer(l));
        }
        synaps = vector<neuronsConnection>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < layers.size() -1 ; i++)
        {
            synaps.push_back(std::move(neuronsConnection(layers[i],layers[i+1])));
        }
    }

    void forward(vector<real> input)
    {
        hiddens[0].ac = input;
        for (int layer = 0; layer < hiddens.size() -1; ++layer)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < synaps[layer].x ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < synaps[layer].y ; j++)
                {
                    hiddens[layer+1].ac[i] += hiddens[layer].ac[j] * synaps[layer].w[i + synaps[layer].x * j]; //+ activation +biais
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0 ; i < hiddens[layer].ac.size() ; i ++)
                hiddens[layer+1].ac[i] = 1.f/(1+exp(-hiddens[layer+1].ac[i]));
        }
    }

    void backward(vector<real> expected)
    {
        vector<real> error(expected);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < error.size(); i ++)
        {
            error[i] = expected[i] - hiddens[hiddens.size() -1].ac[i];
        }
        for (int layer = 0; layer < hiddens.size() -1; ++layer)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < synaps[layer].x ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < synaps[layer].y ; j++)
                {
                    real dw = error[i]*(1+2*exp(-hiddens[0].ac[i])/(1+exp(-hiddens[0].ac[i])));
                    synaps[layer].w[i + synaps[layer].x * j] += dw*alpha;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the main :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<int> net = {64,2};
    network nn(net);
    vector<float> o = {1,0};
    vector<float> t = {0,1};

    auto rOne = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<float>(6,1), std::default_random_engine{});
    auto rTwo = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<float>(3,1), std::default_random_engine{});

    auto gOne = [&](){
        int x=rOne(),y=rOne();
        //while(x=rOne > 8 or x < 0);
        //while(y=rOne > 8 or y < 0);
        std::vector<real> tbr (64,0);
        tbr[x + y*8] = 1.0;
        return tbr;
    };

    auto gTwo = [&](){
        int x=rTwo(),y=rTwo();
        //while(x=rTwo > 8 or x < 0);
        //while(y=rTwo > 8 or y < 0);
        std::vector<real> tbr (64,0);
        tbr[x + y*8] = 1.0;
        return tbr;
    };

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5000 ; i++)
    {
        nn.forward(gOne());
        nn.backward(o);
        nn.forward(gTwo());
        nn.backward(t);
    }
```

I have one major problem and two questions :

1) I receive a SEGFAULT during execution when *backward* is called, it seems that hiddens[0] is empty. So I might (little understatement) have misunderstood how move is working ?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
0x0000000000402159 in network::backward (this=0x7fffffffe190, expected=...) at dnn3.cpp:171
171   real dw = error[i]*(1+2*exp(-hiddens[0].ac[i])/(1+exp( hiddens[0].ac[i])));
(gdb) p i
$1 = 0
(gdb) p hiddens[0].ac[i]
$2 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<float> >::value_type &) @0x3f0000003f000000: <error reading variable>
```

2) Before that the output of the program is :

```
neuronLayer 1
neuronLayer 3
neuronLayer 1
neuronLayer 3
neuronLayer 2
```

Why is the copy constructor called ? I create only 2 layers, and both of them are generated following the exact same process, and only one of them is using this constructor. And I can't understand why it's needed.

3) Concerning the bound objects rOne and rTwo, are they always returning the same value ? cause when I poked into the gOne output it seems that it gave back twice the same value. Is that normal ?

Thanks in advance,
Marc.

EDIT : 
As asked :

```
(gdb) p hiddens
 $1 = {<std::_Vector_base<neuronsLayer, std::allocator<neuronsLayer> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<neuronsLayer>> ={<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<neuronsLayer>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},_M_start = 0x60c1a0, _M_finish = 0x60c1d0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60c1d0}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p hiddens[0].ac
$2 = {<std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<float>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x3f0000003f000000, _M_finish = 0x3f0000003f000000, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60c2e0}}, <No data fields>}
```

EDIT 2 :

```
Breakpoint 1, network::forward (this=0x7fffffffe190, input=...)
(gdb) p hiddens
$1 = {<std::_Vector_base<neuronsLayer, std::allocator<neuronsLayer> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<neuronsLayer>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<neuronsLayer>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},_M_start = 0x60d1a0, _M_finish = 0x60d1d0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60d1d0}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p hiddens[0]
$2 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<neuronsLayer> >::value_type &) @0x60d1a0: { ac = {<std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<float>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x60d1e0, _M_finish = 0x60d2e0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60d2e0}}, <No data fields>}}
(gdb) p hiddens[0].ac
$3 = {<std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<float>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x60d1e0, _M_finish = 0x60d2e0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60d2e0}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p hiddens[1]
$4 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<neuronsLayer> >::value_type &) @0x60d1b8: { ac = {<std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >> = _M_impl = {<std::allocator<float>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x60d180, _M_finish = 0x60d188, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60d188}}, <No data fields>}}
(gdb) p hiddens[1].ac[0] 
$5 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<float> >::value_type &) @0x60d180: 0.100000001
(gdb) p hiddens[0].ac[0]
$6 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<float> >::value_type &) @0x60d1e0: 0.100000001
```

Comment: Your assignment operator in `neuronsLayer` is incorrect. The assignment operator is for assignment to `this` inside the operator function. It should modify `this` and return e.g. `*this`.

Comment: `Why is the copy constructor called`  You should not predict how many times the copy constructor is called.  It may not be called or it may be called multiple times --- it is up to the compiler, optimization settings, etc.

Comment: You mean that I can't, without strong knowledge of the compiler's inside, figure out the whether or not a constructor is called ?

Answer (score 2):

```
neuronsLayer operator=(const neuronsLayer& nl)
{
    std::cout<<"neuronLayer 4"<<std::endl;
    return neuronsLayer(nl);
}
```

The assignment operator did not do what you want. It indeed copied an temporary `neuronsLayer` object according to `nl` passed in, not modifying the content of its caller.

It should be

```
neuronsLayer& operator=(const neuronsLayer& nl)
{
    std::cout<<"neuronLayer 4"<<std::endl;
    ac = nl.ac;
    return *this;
}
```

EDIT : 
As asked :

```
(gdb) p hiddens
 $1 = {<std::_Vector_base<neuronsLayer, std::allocator<neuronsLayer> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<neuronsLayer>> ={<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<neuronsLayer>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},_M_start = 0x60c1a0, _M_finish = 0x60c1d0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60c1d0}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p hiddens[0].ac
$2 = {<std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >> = { _M_impl = {<std::allocator<float>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x3f0000003f000000, _M_finish = 0x3f0000003f000000, _M_end_of_storage = 0x60c2e0}}, <No data fields>}
```

Since `hiddens[0].ac` has `_M_start` equal to `_M_finish`, it is empty, and thus fetching its 0th element leads to segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks I corrected the mistake, but, this operator is not even called once, so it can't be responsible for my problems, right ?

Comment: @Arkantus Please `p hiddens` and `p hiddens[0].ac` when crashing to check whether the 0th element of them exist or not.

Comment: Edited to explain my findings on gdb output.

Comment: I agree with that, I mean segfault does mean that I'am writing where I shouldn't, but why is this vector empty, whereas _forward_ function seems to be working fine ?

Comment: @Arkantus undefined behavior can do anything, including seem to work fine?  Tracking down why one bit of code segfaulted while another did not requires work, and I don't see the immediate return.

Comment: @Yakk The thing is, hiddens is set, and usable during foward (see edit), my question was, what did I didn't understand of c++'s memory management that cause hiddens to be emptied ? (somewhere between forward and backward)